# Assigning two tables separate css styles

Tags: html, css

Why is it that when I apply a style to one table it effects the other even though I've assigned them separate classes. Table two is being pushed down by table twos padding. Have a look at this demo I created. How can I avoid this?

```
<table id="one">
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="two">
    <tr>
      <td>Goodbye</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

css:

```
table{
  display: inline-block;
}

#one{
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#two{
  background-color: orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b7qdcub1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use vertical align to for table [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rww786o/1/)

```css
table{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
}
#one{
  background-color: blue;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#two{
  background-color: orange; 
}
```

```html
  <table id="one">
<tr>
  <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
  </table>
  
  <table id="two">
<tr>
  <td>Goodbye</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks I will be accepting this as the correct answer when it allows me

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add these styles to the tables:

```
table {
   display: block;
   float: left;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/b7qdcub1/2/

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use floats as this is part of an e-marketing leaflet and some email clients don't allow floats

Comment: Than have a look at Mostafa's answer